# pickerView in Swift does not display data

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

This seems too simple to qualify as a post, but I've been stuck on this issue for longer than I'd like. The pickerView does not display the array [durations]. When run, the simulator is just the empty field. The code was copied directly from the UI class, yet it seems to be missing something.

```swift
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var durationPicker: UIPickerView!
    var durations = ["72 hours", "24 hours", "6 hours", "2 hours", "20 minutes"]
    var durationsValue = [72.0, 24.0, 6.0, 2.0, 0.329]
    var itemSelected: String = ""
    var selectedDuration: Double = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return durations[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        itemSelected = durations[row]
        selectedDuration = durationsValue[row]
    }
}
```

Comment: did you set datasource and delegate of picker?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please read more at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `delegate` and the `datasource` inside `viewDidLoad()`

```
durationPicker.delegate = self
durationPicker.dataSource = self
```

Or just connect your picker `delegate` and `datasource` using Xcode interface

Answer (score 0):

I suggest watching this video. This lady does an excellent job explaining various iOS-related topics.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdXmIViD17U

The issue that jumps out at me is you've got arrays specified at the top. Rather than hard-code values in, you should use `return yourArray.count` to return `Int`s.